# What exactly does target_vocab_size mean in the method tfds.features.text.SubwordTextEncoder.build_from_corpus?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp

According to [this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/features/text/SubwordTextEncoder#build_from_corpus), **`target_vocab_size:` int, approximate size of the vocabulary to create.** The statement is pretty ambiguous for me. As far as I can understand, the encoder will map each vocabulary to a unique ID. What will happen if the corpus has `vocab_size` larger than the `target_vocab_size`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/features/text/SubwordTextEncoder) says:

> Encoding is fully invertible because all out-of-vocab wordpieces are byte-encoded

Which means unknown word pieces will be encoded one character at a time. It's best understood through an example. Let's suppose you build a `SubwordTextEncoder` using a very large corpus of English text such that most of the common words are in vocabulary.

```
vocab_size = 10000
tokenizer = tfds.features.text.SubwordTextEncoder.build_from_corpus(
    corpus_sentences, vocab_size)
```

Let's say you try to tokenize the following sentence.

```
tokenizer.encode("good badwords badxyz")
```

It will be tokenized as:

1. good
2. bad
3. words
4. bad
5. x
6. y
7. z

As you can see, since the word piece "xyz" is not in vocabulary it is tokenized as characters.

Comment: What is the algorithm or high-level idea behind `tfds.features.text.SubwordTextEncoder.build_from_corpus`?

Comment: @skytree it takes a set of words and breaks it up in a set of known words in dictionary (or vocabulary). For example, "badwords" is broken up in "bad" and "words". This process is key for good quality natural language processing.

Comment: Thanks. So there is no training in this process? Only mapping from known words to a dictionary?