# TF2.0: SubwordTextEncoder: Tokenizer prints different vocab size but actual no. of words is less

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, nlp, tensorflow2.0

I am using the below snippet to create the tokenizer for a NMT model.

```
tokenizer = tfds.features.text.SubwordTextEncoder.build_from_corpus(
        (en.numpy() for tam, eng in data), target_vocab_size=2**13)
```

When I print the length of the subwords list:

```
print(len(tokenizer.subwords))
# 175
```

But the vocab size is much greater.

```
print(tokenizer.vocab_size)
# 432
```

Shouldn't the vocab size be the length of the list as above?

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't vocab size be the length of the list as above?

No.

Subwords are a subset of the overall vocabulary.  If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/blob/b2b6ff7f55682a275083c5a740174036cd3ec245/tensorflow_datasets/core/features/text/subword_text_encoder.py#L134) for `SubwordTextEncoder`, you can see that the property `vocab_size` returns `1 + len(self._subwords) + text_encoder.NUM_BYTES`.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56308612/what-exactly-does-target-vocab-size-mean-in-the-method-tfds-features-text-subwor) stackoverflow post describes nicely where num bytes comes from.